# Scala expression to replace a file extension in a string

Tags: scala

Here is a version I wrote using split:

```
fileName.split('.').init ++ Seq("js") mkString "."
```

This transforms e.g. `foo.bar.coffee` into `foo.bar.js`.

What I like:

- it works
- it doesn't rely on things like `indexOf()`
- it feels functional ;)

What I don't like:

- it's not as short as I would hope
- it might confuse some readers

How can I write an even simpler / straightforward version?

**UPDATE: Great answers below! In short:**

- seems like my original approach above was not bad although it doesn't cover some corner cases, but that's fixable with a longer expression if you need to cover those
- another, slightly shorter approach uses regexps, which will be more or less readable depending on your regexp background
- a slightly shorter syntax for the original approach (corner cases not covered) reads:

  `fileName.split('.').init :+ "js" mkString "."`

Comment: For the record, this is very straightforward to me.

Comment: I agree with Rafe. I personally like it better than the regular expression versions. However, it does not work well with file names that have no extension. You can get rid of the `++ Seq("js")` by replacing it with `:+ "js"`, by the way.

Comment: Keep in mind that depending on what you want to do, files with double extensions are not treated "correctly", e.g. `x.tar.gz` becomes `x.tar.js`

Comment: @Madoc, cool, hadn't thought of using `:+`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm afraid you actually have to make it *longer* to do what is probably the most sensible robust thing:

```
scala> "oops".split('.').init ++ Seq("js") mkString "."  
res0: String = js
```

Kinda unexpected to lose the name of your file (at least if you're an end user)!

Let's try regex:

```
scala> "oops".replaceAll("\\.[^.]*$", ".js")
res1: java.lang.String = oops
```

Didn't lose the file name, but there's no extension either.  Ack.

Let's fix it:

```
def extensor(orig: String, ext: String) = (orig.split('.') match {
  case xs @ Array(x) => xs
  case y => y.init
}) :+ "js" mkString "."

scala> extensor("oops","js")
res2: String = oops.js

scala> extensor("oops.txt","js")
res3: String = oops.js

scala> extensor("oops...um...","js")
res4: String = oops...js
```

Or with regex:

```
scala> "oops".replaceAll("\\.[^.]*$", "") + ".js" 
res5: java.lang.String = oops.js

scala> "oops.txt".replaceAll("\\.[^.]*$", "") + ".js"
res6: java.lang.String = oops.js

scala> "oops...um...".replaceAll("\\.[^.]*$", "") + ".js"
res7: java.lang.String = oops...um...js
```

(Note the different behavior on the corner case where the filename ends with periods.)

Comment: What I find kind of a waste is that all substrings for period delimited sections of the filename are being created, and then later concatenated again. To avoid this, it would be good to use `lastIndexOf`, which the OP did not like. However, I think it would be a good idea.

Comment: @Madoc - Presumably you're doing these operations because you want to work with files.  How long does a typical file operation take compared to a split + mkString?

Comment: I would expect the VM to optimize this away, anyway.

Comment: @Raphael - You expect too much from the poor VM.  But a few bulk memory copies and a little garbage collection doesn't take many cycles.

Comment: True; for small strings as typical for file names, it might never leave the cache.

Comment: @Rex Kerr: It depends. When I would be writing a one-shot version, then a little wastefulness is not a problem. However, if I were to put the function in a universal library, I would invest a few more lines to optimize it.

Comment: @Madoc - Agreed.  I'd choose differently for a library function for widespread distribution.

Answer (score 3):

Will a simple regex replacement do the trick?

Like:

```
scala> "package.file.java".replaceAll("(\\.[^\\.]*$)", ".rb") 
scala> "package.file.rb"
```

Comment: Haha, hello Eric. You got 12 seconds on me, but mine is 2 chars shorter. ;)

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with lastIndexOf?

```
fileName.take(1 + fileName.lastIndexOf(".")) + "js"
```

Of course if you want to keep the fileName when it doesn't contain any dot, you need to do a little bit more

```
(if (fileName.contains('.')) fileName.take(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")) 
else fileName) + ".js"
```

Comment: Nothing absolutely wrong with indexes. But in essence I was trying to see where other approaches lead you. It's a bit like the difference between using `for (i = 0; i < foo.length; i++)` and using `for (f < foo)`: sometime indexes do not actually reflect closely what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Very easy with lastIndexOf, and work with file name that contains more than one dot

```
def getFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName: String): String = {
  fileName.dropRight(fileName.length - fileName.lastIndexOf("."))
}

val fileName = "foo.bar.coffee"

getFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + ".js"
```

Result is foo.bar.js

Answer (score 2):

You could always use the `replaceAll` method on `java.lang.String`

```
scala> "foo.bar.coffee".replaceAll("\\.[^.]*$", ".js")
res11: java.lang.String = foo.bar.js
```

It's shorter but less readable.

Answer (score 2):

So, I'll go for speed here. As it happens, `substring` is constant time because it simply does not copy the string. So,

```
((index: Int) => (
) + ".js")(fileName lastIndexOf '.')
```

This uses a closure, which will slow it down a bit. Faster:

```
def addJS(fileName: String) = {
    def addJSAt(index: Int) = (
        if (index >= 0) fileName substring (0, index) 
        else fileName
    ) + ".js"

    addJSAt(fileName lastIndexOf '.')
}
```

**EDIT:** As it happens, Java now does copy the string on `substring`.

Comment: Something is wrong when you are going for speed and I'm writing pattern matches and saying not to worry....

Comment: @Rex Hey, is not like you left me anything else to go for... :-)

Comment: I know this is ancient, just wondering if there is performance or other reason for using a nested function rather than something like `def addJS(fileName: String) = {
    val index = fileName lastIndexOf '.'
    (if (index >= 0) fileName substring (0, index) 
    else fileName
    ) + ".js"
}`

Comment: @Davos No reason, I just like it that way.

Answer (score 1):

*If you know what the current extension is*, then you could do this:

```
def replaceExtension(fileName: String, oldExt: String, newExt: String): String =
  fileName.stripSuffix(oldExt) + newExt

// Be sure to use `.` when calling:
replaceExtension(fileName, ".javascript", ".js")
```